How to use app script to add custom properties to a file?
I am trying to write a app script that add some custom properties to the file that stored in shared Drive. After trying multiple ways and reading through the documentationtext, I still can't succeed adding or getting properties of a file.
Here is my coding for adding the AppProperties:
function addAppProperty(fileId) {
  try {
    let file = {
      'appProperties': {
        'department': 'Sales'
      }
    };
    // Updates a file to add an app property.
    file = Drive.Files.update(file, fileId, null, {'fields': 'id,appProperties'});
    console.log(
        'ID: %s, appProperties: %s',
        file.id,
        JSON.stringify(file.appProperties, null, 2));
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer) - Handle exception
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}

which is from the documentation, this works well, but when I try to return the properties of a file and search for property, I've encountered many errors:
function getProperty() {
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('properties has { key="department" and value="Sales" }');
  
  if(files.hasNext) {
    var file = files.next();
    console.log(file.getName());
  }
  else{
    console.log("No file founded")
  }
} 

With error  Exception: Invalid argument: q,  regard to this line  var file = files.next();
I have no clue how to solve this problem, Very appreciate to any kind of Help!

Modification points:

From your showing script, the function addAppProperty stores the custom property using Drive API v3. And, the function getProperty tries to retrieve the property using the Drive service (DriveApp). In the current stage, the Drive service (DriveApp) uses Drive API v2.
In the function addAppProperty, it seems that you want to store the private custom property. In this case, the same client is required to be used. Please be careful about this.

When these points are reflected in your script, please test the following modified script.
Modified script:
In this modification, please use the same Google Apps Script project for storing and loading the private custom property. So, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the same Google Apps Script project. And, enable Drive API v3.
Please set your file ID. And, run the function addAppProperty. And then, run the function getProperty. By this, the file name of the file searched by the stored private custom property is shown in the log.
// 1. Store the private custom property.
function addAppProperty() {
  const fileId = "###"; // Please set your file ID.

  try {
    let file = { 'appProperties': { 'department': 'Sales' } };
    // Updates a file to add an app property.
    file = Drive.Files.update(file, fileId, null, { 'fields': 'id,appProperties' });
    console.log(
      'ID: %s, appProperties: %s',
      file.id,
      JSON.stringify(file.appProperties, null, 2));
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer) - Handle exception
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}

// 2. Search files with the private custom property.
function getProperty() {
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("properties has { key='department' and value='Sales' and visibility='PRIVATE' }");

  if (files.hasNext) {
    var file = files.next();
    console.log(file.getName());
  }
  else {
    console.log("No file founded")
  }
}

Note:
If you want to use the different Google Apps Script projects for storing and loading the custom property, please use the public custom property. In this case, you can use the following sample script.
function addAppProperty() {
  const fileId = "###"; // Please set your file ID.

  try {
    let file = { 'properties': { 'department': 'Sales' } };
    // Updates a file to add an app property.
    file = Drive.Files.update(file, fileId, null, { 'fields': 'id,appProperties' });
    console.log(
      'ID: %s, appProperties: %s',
      file.id,
      JSON.stringify(file.appProperties, null, 2));
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer) - Handle exception
    console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}

function getProperty() {
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("properties has { key='department' and value='Sales' and visibility='PUBLIC' }");

  if (files.hasNext) {
    var file = files.next();
    console.log(file.getName());
  }
  else {
    console.log("No file founded")
  }
}

References:

Drive API v2 and v3 comparison reference
Method: files.update of Drive API v3


many thanks, you solved my problem! I didn't realize visibility='PUBLIC' is necessary here, documentation also didn't talk about it :((

another question: how can I use file.get to return the properties of a certain file?'
var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId, {
supportsAllDrives: true,
fields: 'properties'
});

@Yunlong About many thanks, you solved my problem!, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

@Yunlong About your new question another question: how can I use file.get to return the properties of a certain file?' var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId, { supportsAllDrives: true, fields: 'properties' });, in that case, how about Drive.Files.get(fileId, { supportsAllDrives: true, fields: 'properties,appProperties' }) or Drive.Files.get(fileId, { supportsAllDrives: true, fields: '*' })?
